# Text classification process kills when I am using linear SVM for 10000 rows

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I am programming in python 2.7 with NLTK library for both text prepossessing and classification in sentiment analysis. I am using nltk wrapper of scikit-learn algorithms. bellow code is after prepossessing and separation to train and test sets.

```
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC, NuSVC

training_set = nltk.classify.util.apply_features(extractFeatures, trainTweets)
testing_set = nltk.classify.util.apply_features(extractFeatures, testTweets)

#LinearSVC 
LinearSVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
LinearSVC_classifier.train(training_set)
LinearSVCAccuracy = nltk.classify.accuracy(LinearSVC_classifier, testing_set)*100

print "LinearSVC accuracy percentage:" + str(LinearSVCAccuracy)
```

it works fine when the number of rows are like 4000 tweets for training, but when it increases to for example 10000 tweets, possess is getting killed with following error.

> Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 24293 (python) score 848 or
>
> > sacrifice child
>
> Killed process 24293, UID 29091, (python) total-vm:14569168kB,
>
> > anon-rss:14206656kB, file-rss:3412kB
>
> Clocksource tsc unstable (delta = -17179861691 ns). Enable clocksource
>
> > failover by adding clocksource_failover kernel parameter.

RAM of my pc is 8 Gig but I even tried with 16 Gig RAM and still has problem. How can I Classify this amount for tweets without any problem?

Comment: Try scikit without NLTK, does the memoryerror still occur?

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you running? Which python distribution? Try to install cython and/or using scikit-learn directly. Have a look at [scikit-learn optimization techniques](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/performance.html)